# Set alarm for every other day?

Tags: alarm

In the default Android clock app, you can set an alarm for specific days of the week, but not a more flexible schedule such as repeating every other day or only the third Thursday of the month.

Is there a better alarm app that offers that flexibility? Using the calendar allows more sophisticated repetition but only notification, not alarm functionality.

Comment: Just a heads-up that we have a sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) for this specific purpose, in case you're interested.

Comment: thanks, wasn't sure if this was a dev focussed or s/w (seemed to be a bit of both) so might be better to ask over there

Comment: Cross-posted to SoftRecs.SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/82900/520